# Cannot mkdir, file not found

Tags: python, panda3d

I'm making a game, and I made a log system. It makes a new directory and makes a .log file in it.
I released it today only to find that it doesn't work. It works fine for me, yet not to others. I have tried makedirs but to no avail. Here is the code:

```
if not os.path.exists('C:/ToontownRebuilt/src/user/logs/'):
    os.mkdir('C:/ToontownRebuilt/src/user/logs/client')
    self.notify.info('Made new directory to save logs.')
```

and here is the traceback the people (one reported it to me) suffering the error got:

```
:ClientStart: Reading user/preferences.json...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ToontownRebuilt\src\dependencies\panda\python\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "C:\ToontownRebuilt\src\dependencies\panda\python\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "C:\ToontownRebuilt\src\toontown\toonbase\ClientStart.py", line 94, in <module>
__builtin__.launcher = TTSLauncher()
File "toontown\launcher\TTSLauncher.py", line 34, in __init__
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/ToontownRebuilt/src/user/logs/client'
```

Any help is appreciated with this issue. It has gotten me beat. It works for me, but not others. Why? How can I fix it? Also, if this question wasn't good, can you comment some tips on how to make it better? Thank you! :D

Comment: How sure are you that your users are running the script/executable with permissions for writing and execution?

Comment: @SeanM This might be the problem. I need to try them running it as admin. Is there a simple method of requesting administrator permissions within a python script?

Comment: The simplest way to solve this problem is to either `try...except` like Rolf suggests OR make a new installer that includes all directories rather than relying on os.mkdir() to create the ones you need.

Comment: Then again, that would leave the error of not being able to make the logs themselves. By using a try..except around the log creation I managed to fix it for the person. Thanks to everyone for your help. :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could make use of a `try..except` statement, if the path must be fixed.

```
if not os.path.exists('C:/ToontownRebuilt/src/user/logs/'):
    try:
         os.mkdir('C:/ToontownRebuilt/src/user/logs/client')
         print('Made new directory to save logs.')
    except:
         print("Unable to create C:/ToontownRebuilt/src/logs/client\nPlease create manually and try again.")
```

Comment: Seems like it would fix the problem. Atleast to an extent that they will be able to play the game. Tomorrow they will be awake, I'll let you know if it works for them.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had the same error with them with making logs, so this worked fine for that too.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, it just prints a custom error message...

Comment: @Sindarus Yes it does and in so doing informs the user how to resolve the problem. Perhaps you have a solution to resolve a permissions issue without knowing the admin password. If so I'd love to see it, care to post an answer of your own?

Answer (score 0):

The other users may not have directories called

```
    ToontownRebuilt
    user
```

Or

```
    src
```

Shorten to:

```
    os.mkdir('user/logs/client')
```

Comment: They do, because I made an installer that extracts to C:\. It works for me, so it _should_ work for them, but it doesn't. Thanks for putting in your 2 cents, though.